# I'm in the process of creating a gui program with Python, but the job doesn't run

Tags: tkinter, operating-system, macos-catalina

If you look at the GUI program training video, there is no error in coding, but it can be executed. However, the completion statements and tasks do not appear and do not work. I'd appreciate it if you could check what's wrong with the code. I'm currently working with MacBook

```
import os
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.messagebox as msgbox
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image




root = Tk()
root.title("Instem GUI")
# root.geometry("0") # 가로 * 세로

# 파일추가, Add File
def add_file():
    files = filedialog.askopenfilenames(title="이미지 파일을 선택하세요", \
        filetypes=(("PNG 파일", "*.png"), ("모든 파일", "*.*")), \
        initialdir="://Users/king/Desktop/practica")
        # 최초에 사용자가 지정하누 경로를 열어줌
    # 선택된 파일 목록
    for file in files:
        list_file.insert(END, file)

# 선택 삭제, Delete Selection
def del_file():
    for index in reversed(list_file.curselection()):
        list_file.delete(index)

# 저장 경로(폴더), Storage Path (Folder)
def browse_dest_path():
    folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory()
    if folder_selected is None: # 사용자가 취소를 누를 때
        return
   # print(folder_selected)
    txt_dest_path.delete(0, END)
    txt_dest_path.insert(0, folder_selected)
    
# 이미지 통합, Image integration
def merge_image():
   # print(list_file.get(0, END)) # 모든 파일 목록을 가져오기
    images = [Image.open(x) for x in list_file.get(0, END)]
    # size -> size[0] : width, size[1] : height
    widths = [x.size[0] for x in images]
    heights = [x.size[1] for x in  images]
    
    max_width, total_height = max(widths), sum(heights)
    
    # 스케치북 준비, Preparing a Sketchbook
    result_img = Image.new("RGB", (max_width, total_height), (255,255,255))
    y_offset = 0
    for img in images:
        result_img.paste(img, (0, y_offset))
        y_offset += img.size[1]

    dest_path = os.path.join(txt_dest_psth.get(), "instem_photo.jpg") 
    result_img.save(dest_path)
    msgbox.showinfo("알림", "작업이 완료되었습니다.")



# 시작, start
def start():
    # 각 옵션들 값을 확인, Check the value of each option
    print("가로넓이 : ", cmb_width.get())
    print("간격 : ", cmb_space.get())
    print("포맷 : ", cmb_format.get())

    #  파일 목록 확인, Check the file list
    if list_file.size() == 0:
        msgbox.showwarning("경고", "이미지 파일을 추가해주세요")
        return
    # 저장 목록 확인, Check Save List
    if len(txt_dest_path.get()) == 0:
        msgbox.showwarning("경고", "저장 경로를 선택하세요")  
        return

 
# 파일 프레임 파일추가, adding a file frame file
file_frame = Frame(root)
file_frame.pack(fill="x", padx=5, pady=5)

btn_add_file = Button(file_frame, padx=5, pady=5, width=10, text="파일추가", command=add_file)
btn_add_file.pack(side="left")

btn_del_file = Button(file_frame, padx=5, pady=5, width=10, text="선택삭제", command=del_file)
btn_del_file.pack(side="right")

# 리스트 프레임, List Frame
list_frame = Frame(root)
list_frame.pack(fill="both", padx=5, pady=5)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(list_frame)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

list_file = Listbox(list_frame, selectmode="extended", height=15, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
list_file.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
scrollbar.config(command=list_file.yview)


# 저장 경로  프레임, Storage Path Frame
path_frame = LabelFrame(root, text="저장경로")
path_frame.pack(fill="x", padx=5, pady=5, ipady=5)

txt_dest_path = Entry(path_frame)
txt_dest_path.pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=True, padx=5, pady=5, ipady=4)

btn_dest_path = Button(path_frame, text="찾아보기", width=10, command=browse_dest_path)
btn_dest_path.pack(side="right")

# 옵션 프레임, Option Frame
# 
frame_option = LabelFrame(root, text="Option") 
frame_option.pack(padx=5, pady=5) # Add to Screen

# 가로 넓이, horizontal and horizontal
lbl_width = Label(frame_option, text="가로넓이", width=8) # Put the width in the frame option and zoom in about 3 times the width
lbl_width.pack(side="left") # Add to left screen

# 가로 넓이 콤보, a horizontal combo , Use ttk to use combo 
opt_width = ["원본유지", "1024", "800", "640"] # 
cmb_width = ttk.Combobox(frame_option, state="readonly", values=opt_width, width=10) # Use read-only to receive only values that I specify without receiving the properties specified by the read-only user
cmb_width.current(0) # 첫번째 값을 자동으로 사용 
cmb_width.pack(side="left", padx=5, pady=5)


# 이미지 간격 옵션, Image Interval
lbl_width = Label(frame_option, text="간격", width=8)
lbl_width.pack(side="left")

# 간격 옵션 콤보, Interval Options Combo
opt_space = ["없음", "좁게", "보통", "넓게"]
cmb_space = ttk.Combobox(frame_option, state="readonly", values=opt_space, width=10)
cmb_space.current(0)
cmb_space.pack(side="left", padx=5, pady=5)


# 파일 포맷 옵션, File Format Options
lbl_format = Label(frame_option, text="포맷", width=8)
lbl_width.pack(side="left")

# 파일 포맷 옵션 콤보, File Format Options Combo
opt_format = ["PNG", "JPG", "BMP"]
cmb_format = ttk.Combobox(frame_option, state="readonly", values=opt_format, width=10)
cmb_format.current(0)
cmb_format.pack(side="left", padx=5, pady=5)

# 진행 상황, progress
frame_progress = LabelFrame(root, text="진행상황")
frame_progress.pack(fill="x", padx=5, pady=5)

p_var = DoubleVar()
progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(frame_progress, maximum=100, variable=p_var)
progress_bar.pack(fill="x", padx=5, pady=5)

# 실행, Press the Start button to start the image integration task
frame_run = Frame(root)
frame_run.pack(fill="x", padx=5, pady=5)
# 닫기 버튼, close btn
btn_close = Button(frame_run, padx=5, pady=5, text="close", width=12, command=root)
btn_close.pack(side="right", padx=5, pady=5)
# 시작 버튼, start btn
btn_start = Button(frame_run, padx=5, pady=5, text="start", width=12, command=start)
btn_start.pack(side="right", padx=5, pady=5)


root.resizable(False, False) # x(너비), y(높이) 값 변경 불가 / 창 크기 조정 설정
 
root.mainloop()
```

I'm in the process of creating a gui program with Python, but the job doesn't run

Comment: Can you add English comments beside the Buttons and Label's? it'll be easier for us if you do so.

Comment: I modified it. Is this correct?

Comment: I am not sure if it's correct I don't speak Korean. Can u also add English comments beside buttons and labels? (like: `btn_start = Button(frame_run, padx=5, pady=5, text="시작", width=12, command=start)` beside this button. I need to know what the text is)

Comment: I modified it, but I don't know the exact text because I'm not good enough. First of all, I wrote it down as I said in the educational video.

Comment: It looks like you've missed something in `start()`. Add a call to the function that does the processing there. [Here's a google translate of the source code](https://pastebin.com/Ksxd4K7m) if anyone needs it.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. It's finally working.^.^